# How is $\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{x^2} = \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{x^2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{x^2}$

is equal to

$\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{x^2}}$

But I'm not sure how to see it. What operations can  I do on the first to get the second? Is this a common method?

Comment: Hint: Rationalize the denominator.

Comment: $$a-b=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}$$

Comment: Okay, I see how they're equal but why would you want to move from the left expression to the right? We're proving convergence is uniform

Comment: This is a more than classical trick. Always carry it in your toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sqrt{x^2 + \dfrac1n} - \sqrt{x^2}\equiv\left(\sqrt{x^2 + \dfrac1n} - \sqrt{x^2}\right)\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac1n} + \sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac1n} + \sqrt{x^2}}$$

Now, recall that $(a - b)(a + b)\equiv a^2 - b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the numerator and denominator by:
$$\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{x^2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} +\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} +\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt{x^2 + \frac{1}{n}} + \sqrt{x^2}}$$